# Display a linked list

Tags: c++, list, linked-list

I am new to C++ and I'm making a linked list. I keep running into issues when trying to display the contents of my linked list. It either shows random numbers, deletes items from it, or crashes completely. I'm not sure how to fix it or if the issue is coming from elsewhere in the program, but I'm not sure from where since the rest of the program runs fine.

```
class CarNode {
public:
    CarNode() : m_pNext(0), m_ticketNum(0) { }
    ~CarNode();
    CarNode(CarNode &): m_pNext(0), m_ticketNum(0) { }
    void SetNext(CarNode* p){m_pNext=p;}
    void SetTicketNum(int tN){m_ticketNum=tN;}
    CarNode *GetNext(void){return(m_pNext);}
    int GetTicketNum(void){return(m_ticketNum);}

    private:
    int m_ticketNum;
    CarNode *m_pNext;
};


class CAlley {
public:
    CAlley () : m_pTop(0), mSize(0), mMaxSize(MAXSIZE) { }
    ~CAlley () {}
    CAlley (CAlley &):m_pTop(0), mSize(0), mMaxSize(MAXSIZE) { }
    int Park(int);
    void Retrieve(int,CAlley *);
    void Terminate();
    void Display();

private:
    void SetTop(CarNode *p){m_pTop=p;}
    bool Empty(){return ((mSize==0) ? true : false);}
    bool Full() {return ((mSize==MAXSIZE) ? true : false);}
    int Push(CarNode *);
    CarNode * Pop();
    CarNode *m_pTop;
    int mSize;
    int mMaxSize;
};


void CAlley::Display()
{
    cout << "Alley A:\t";
    CarNode * pCurr = m_pTop;
    while (pCurr != NULL)
    {
        cout << pCurr->GetTicketNum();
        if(pCurr->GetNext()!=NULL)
            cout<< '\t';
        pCurr=pCurr->GetNext();

    }
    cout << '\n';
}
```

Comment: When you used the debugger, which lines were giving issues?

Comment: I actually just found where my error was and it was in my Retrieve function that caused my display to crash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm probably running on a different set up to you, but does setting your pointers to (0) actually set them to NULL? if not you may want to do that explicitly.

I think we may need your push/pop to properly test.

As an aside, I got it written up nicely to test on codepad.org - http://codepad.org/C15VzSKT
`

Comment: Thanks, that was really helpful, and your code looked better than mine,  however I found the main reason my program was crashing was in my Retrieve function.